# Insert a section that appears only according to user's permissions

Tags: permissions, confluence

When editing a Confluence page, is there a way to insert some text block or section that is only shown to specific users based on their permissions or roles?

I know that a workaround may be to split the info into multiple pages and assign restrictions to every page separately, but this approach will force the privileged users to browse multiple pages to get the whole information they need.

Comment: Perhaps including restricted content via excerpt-include macro would work...

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Montag451 I found a work around.
A plgin called [visibility](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.customware.confluence.plugin.visibility/server/overview), enables you to show/hide content according to some criteria, but this is just in the browser.
If you exported the page or showed the page source, all the content will appear.

Comment: Unfortunately this plugin is just for the server model. We are using Confluence in the cloud. Thanks anyway.